# Azure arm output the IPs of an app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using ARM template in azure  to get the possibleOutboundIpAddresses from an app service and use the same to create allow firewall rule in mysql server

Below is the parameter I am using to fetch the ips

```
"parameters": {
        "webAppOutboundIpAddresses": {
            "value": "[split(reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',parameters('wpsitename'))).properties.possibleOutboundIpAddresses,',')]"
```

and below is the piece of code using in the linked template.

```
            "type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerName'), '/Allow WebApp Outbound IP ',copyIndex('webAppOutboundIPAddressesCopy'))]",
        
         "properties": {
            "startIpAddress": "[parameters('webAppOutboundIpAddresses')[copyIndex('webAppOutboundIPAddressesCopy')]]",
            "endIpAddress": "[parameters('webAppOutboundIpAddresses')[copyIndex('webAppOutboundIPAddressesCopy')]]"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "webAppOutboundIPAddressesCopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('webAppOutboundIpAddresses'))]"
```

But somehow the pipeline is failing and I am getting an invalid parameter error

```
InvalidParameterValue",
    "message": "Invalid value given for parameter '{0}'. Specify a valid parameter value."
```

One more thing I noticed is the output IPs are showing inside square brackets like ["192.168.1.2"]

Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the resource is in the same template, you must use the reference() function and pass it the resource id or only the name:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "appServiceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specifies the name of the Azure App Service"
            }
        },
        "appServicePlanName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "app",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false
            },
            "resources": [],
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "appServiceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "reference(parameters('appServiceName'), '2016-03-01', 'Full').properties.inboundIpAddress"
        },
        "ipAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "whatingodsnamegoeshere"
        }
    }
}
```

OR
With resourced id:

```
reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlanName')), '2016-03-01', 'Full').properties.inboundIpAddress
```

For the outbound ip addresses: refer [here](https://aztoso.com/arm%20templates/arm-nightmare-reference/) provided by AZToso.

```
"parameters": {
            "webAppOutboundIpAddresses": {
                "value": "[split(reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',variables('webAppName'))).possibleOutboundIpAddresses,',')]"
            },
```

We must develop a loop to iterate through the list of potential outbound IP addresses for a Web App so that we can add each one to the SQL firewall. This is possible with ARM templates by utilizing the [copy element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources). We must utilize the [reference function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference) to obtain the WebApp's object. However, the reference function has a restriction that prevents you from using it to change the value of the count property in a copy loop.